# Laravel do not validate if field is not required

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I've got the following request validation:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class OwnerEstate extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'firstname' => 'required_if:type,individual',
            'secondname'=> 'required_if:type,individual',
            'lastname' => 'required_if:type,individual',
            'pin' => 'required_if:type,individual|digits:10',

            'name' => 'required_if:type,legal-entity',
            'eik' => 'required_if:type,legal-entity|digits:9'
        ];
    }
}
```

And when the type is not individual it still checks for the **'digits:10'** validation of the pin and returns an error. How do I disable the other validation if required_if validation does not require the field. **(I'm using Laravel  5.5)**

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`digits:10` is completely separate from `required_if`, so it will validate whether or not the field is required.  However, if you want to also allow null or empty values (assuming the field is not required), you can add the rule `nullable`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-nullable